# MiKTeX PDF Viewer Extremely Blurry

Tags: texworks, viewers, miktex2.9

I'm new to LaTeX and having trouble with the pdf viewer. When I compile my document, the pdf viewer is extremely blurry - barely readable - at what seems like a reasonable level of zoom (Fit to Width, in a window half the size of my monitor). The pdf looks fine when I print it or even open it in Adobe Acrobat, but MiKTeX's TeXworks pdf viewer almost hurts to try to read. This is frustrating when I'm tweaking formatting and want to see how small changes look without having to open the pdf in Adobe every time I compile. This piece of a screenshot shows the .tex file on the left (which looks crisp and clear on my monitor), and the pdf viewer on the right.

[image: crisp and blurry]

The other similar questions I've found on here were from people who had problems with the font coming out blurry in the actual pdf (in any viewer), not just the TeXworks viewer. Mine looks fine in the Adobe viewer, so I'm skeptical that this is a font issue. Is there any way to make the TeXworks viewer less blurry? I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have the latest version (TeXworks 0.6.3)?

Comment: The TeXworks folder contains a folder called "0.6", which I think is the version number

Comment: Strange… I have no TeXworks folder. You'll find the version in the Help menu, About TeX works. If you do hace version 0.6, it dates back to April 2016. I suggest you update with MiKTeX console.

Comment: Okay, the Help menu says it is version 0.6.3. I didn't know to look there, so I was poking around in my computer's Apps folder and that's where I found the TeXworks folder

Comment: There was a difference in the graphics engine that MiKTeX used to compile TeXworks compared to master TeXworks version (mainly affected invisibility of Chinese fonts, clarity of others should have been OK) it is best not to substitute one for the other but a portable (throwaway)TeXworks should prove if its their QT engine not working well with your hardware (common issue with Hi-Res monitor scaling) MiKTeX TeXworks does not allow change res or chain any other 2ndary lightweight viewer other than via `viewer` `scripts` `default viewer` (adobe?). I think only one user found remove adobe helped !